# vba for cut and paste is too slow

Tags: vba

I have two protected sheets:

1. Customer Stock
2. Collected Stock

Once a customer collects the stock, I trigger column (G:CustomerRow) in Customer Stock Sheet and it automatically cuts and paste above the first row (“2:2”) in the Collected Stock Sheet.

The problem is the VBA code takes too long to do that.

Somebody told my code has to be edited to avoid things like too many .selects etc.

Can somebody help me to modify my code to speed up the cut paste macro? 
All I need is a macro for removing one row and pasting its values to another sheet above row ("2:2")

In the Customer Stock Sheet, the code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Column = Columns(7).Column Then 'where G is the seventh column
If Target.Value <> "" Then
Call CustomerCollected
End If
End If
End Sub
```

In the module:

```
Sub CustomerCollected()

Dim actCell
actCell = Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row)
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Response = MsgBox("Do you want to transfer this Customer from Customer Stock to      Collected Stock?", vbYesNo)
If Response <> 6 Then
Exit Sub
End If
If Response = 6 Then
Worksheets("Collected Stock").Unprotect Password:="a27826" ' change the password to    whatever you wish
If actCell <= Date Then
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Cut
Sheets("Collected Stock").Select
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Customer Stock").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Range("A1").Select
End If
Worksheets("Collected Stock").Protect Password:="a27826", _
DrawingObjects:=True, _
Contents:=True, _
Scenarios:=True, _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
AllowSorting:=False, _
AllowFiltering:=False, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Why not try to modify your code first and then post if you have any questions?

Answer (score 1):

You hardly ever need to use .Select for anything - you can access an objects properties directly without selecting it first. i.e. :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value <> "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False '// Prevent infinite loop
      CustomerCollected
    Application.EnableEvents = True '// Re-enable events
   End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub CustomerCollected()

'// Check user wants to transfer row, if no then exit
If MsgBox("Do you want to transfer this Customer from Customer Stock to Collected Stock?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'// Cut active row and insert into other workbook
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
With Sheets("Collected Stock")
    .Unprotect "a27826"
    .Rows(2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Protect "a27826"
End With
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I've also re-written the first sub to show you an example of how to use logical operators ("And", "Or", "Not") in an If statement rather than multiple If blocks. Another thing I've done is turned off events, as the sub being called also changes the worksheet you could potentially end up in an infinite loop unless you temporarily switch them off. Always something to be mindful of when working with events procedures.

Comment: thanx a lot. its a lot faster but the code you provided does not delete the row in the source sheet "Customer Stock"